# XML Nested data for vb

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Thanks to help elsewhere on this site i fixed my original problem however have a new one.

I need to be able to pull the name field of the branches to populate a combo box, without showing the path.

once selected and the button clicked it must copy all files under the path of the selected branch to a USB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Versions>
    <Version>
        <Trunk>GapGun Software Version 7.1</Trunk>
            <Branch Name=".142" Path="\\MEDIA-SERVER\Plex"/>
            <Branch>.145</Branch>
            <Branch>.148</Branch>
            <Branch>.153</Branch>
            <Branch>.176</Branch>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <Trunk>GapGun Software Version 7.2</Trunk>
            <Branch>.152</Branch>
            <Branch>.155</Branch>
            <Branch>.158</Branch>
            <Branch>.163</Branch>
            <Branch>.166</Branch>
    </Version>
</Versions>
```

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Response As Object

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim xelement As XElement = XElement.Load("F:\Test.xml")

        Dim Versions As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Elements()

        For Each Version In Versions
            Console.WriteLine(Version.Element("Trunk").Value)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(Version.Element("Trunk").Value)
        Next Version

        ComboBox3.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Text = ""
        Dim xelement As XElement = XElement.Load("F:\Test.xml")
        Dim name =
        From nm In xelement.Elements("Version")
        Where CStr(nm.Element("Trunk")) = ComboBox1.Text
        Select nm

        For Each xEle As XElement In name
            Dim branches = xEle.Elements("Branch").Select(Function(el) el.Value).ToArray()

            Console.WriteLine(xEle)
            ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(branches)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

[just for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgz0C.jpg)

Also i have no problem restructuring xml if it needs to the is only a sandbox at the moment.

Comment: and what's the question? are you getting any error?

Comment: How do i get the branch e.g. .142 into a combobox without displaying the path and then when i click the button copy the files from the path to a usb. The program will be used to select a version of the software and copy the files to a usb for install, but each branch is stored in a different location.        I've edited the question to make that clearer

Comment: Use code from you previous posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985365/reading-xml-data-using-linq-multiple-elements-with-the-same-name-vb

Comment: I have an that worked for the branch but i cant figure out how to use the path

Comment: You have two formats for branches. Which one is correct? the one with name and path and the one that has no name or path but a text? Also, this seems to be winforms, why do you have Console.WriteLine() calls inside? Were you copy/pasting these lines from somewhere else?

Comment: The console is purely for debug that will not be in the final code, the xml can be formatted however is best, i have 0 experience with XML hence why im having so many issues. the xml must contain; trunk (7.1 7.2 etc), Branches (.432 .654 etc) and network paths to the folder containing the files for that version of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "GapGun Software Version 7.1" and then ".142", click on Button1 and you'll get the path.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Response As Object
    Private xelement As XElement = XElement.Load("F:\Test.xml")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Versions As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Elements()
        For Each Version In Versions
            Console.WriteLine(Version.Element("Trunk").Value)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(Version.Element("Trunk").Value)
        Next Version

        ComboBox3.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Text = ""
        Dim name =
        From nm In xelement.Elements("Version")
        Where CStr(nm.Element("Trunk")) = ComboBox1.Text
        Select nm

        For Each xEle As XElement In name
            Dim branches = xEle.Elements("Branch").ToDictionary( _
                   Function(k) If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(k.Value), k.Attribute("Name").Value, k.Value), _
                   Function(v) If(v.Attribute("Path") Is Nothing, "", v.Attribute("Path").Value))

            Console.WriteLine(xEle)
            ComboBox2.DataSource = New BindingSource(branches, Nothing)
            ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Key"
            ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Value"
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim name = ComboBox2.SelectedText
        Dim path = ComboBox2.SelectedValue
        If Not path = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show(path)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Combo box items have two properties: `Text` and `Value`, so it's handy to put something in property value so you don't require another query to find it afterwards. In `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` I put the branch name as text and the path as value for each item of `ComboBox2`.

Also moved `xelement` as a member of the class because it's being used by multiple methods and it was parsing the same file many times.

Comment: Great, Thank you very much! solved my problem and now my problem works great with a little tinkering!